# use Builder pattern combined with protected access modifier

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder

I'm reading a book in Design Patterns, and below is some code example used by the author. The author tries to build a html builder as:

```
public class HtmlElement
{
    public string Name, Text;
    public List<HtmlElement> Elements = new List<HtmlElement>();

    public HtmlElement() { }
    public HtmlElement(string name, string text)
    {
        Name = name;
        Text = text;
    }
    // factory method
    public static HtmlBuilder Create(string name)
    {
       return new HtmlBuilder(name);
    } 
}

//builder class
public class HtmlBuilder
{
    protected readonly string rootName;
    protected HtmlElement root = new HtmlElement();
    public HtmlBuilder(string rootName)
    {
        this.rootName = rootName;
        root.Name = rootName;
    }
    public HtmlBuilder AddChild(string childName, string childText)
    {
        var e = new HtmlElement(childName, childText);
        root.Elements.Add(e);
        return this;            //fluent api
    }

     // to return a HtmlElement object
    public static implicit operator HtmlElement(HtmlBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.root;
    }
    public override string ToString() => root.ToString();
}
```

then the author says:

**"To simply force users to use the Builder whenever they are constructing a `HtmlElement` object,  we have hidden all constructors of `HtmlElement` class as":**

```
public class HtmlElement
{
   ...
   protected HtmlElement() { }
   protected HtmlElement(string name, string text)
   {
      Name = name;
      Text = text;
   }
   ...
}
```

so users can go like

```
HtmlElement root = HtmlElement.Create("ul").AddChildFluent("li", "hello").AddChildFluent("li", "world");

Console.WriteLine(root);
```

here is what I don't understand, the author changed the access modifier of `HtmlElement`'s constructors to `protected`, which means that `HtmlBuilder` class cannot access to the protected constructors like

```
protected HtmlElement root = new HtmlElement();    // not allowed
```

so does it mean that we need to let the `HtmlBuilder` inherit from `HtmlElement`? But they are no inheritance context at all, so how can I modify it?

Comment: HtmlBuilder does not inherit from HtmlElement. The author simply asks user not to use the constructor to instantiate/ build HtmlElement, but instead use the builder `HtmlElement.Create(`...

Comment: @kurakura88  how can we use the factory method in the HtmlBuilder's constructor? that will lead to infinite loop, I have tried that, stackoverflow immediately. Besides, your code doesn't compile neither

Answer (score 0):

That code is wrong. The builder class cannot have access. The author probably intended to use the factory method.

I do not agree with the author at all.

Never try to force users to use classes in a certain way just to fit a pattern. The whole point of the builder pattern is to reduce complexity when building objects, not make it harder.

The builder pattern is most often used when a chain of objects are being constructed and not simple objects like an HTML element. For instance you can have a CarBuilder which constructs a car with an engine, transmission, and all other objects required to get a functional car.

You might have a `SafeCarBuilder` which uses a stronger chassi but the same engine and a `FastCarBuilder` which uses the default chassi but adds a turbo to the engine.

Comment: how can we use the factory method in the `HtmlBuilder`'s constructor? that will lead to infinite loop

Comment: It should not return the HtmlBuilder, it's a violation of Dependecy Inversion Principle. The HtmlElement is on a lower abstraction level and should not be dependent of HtmlBuilder. I would throw out that book and get the original Design Patterns book instead, it's great.

Comment: may I ask you to write the complete code for `HtmlBuilder`, please? Im curious how the code will be